# C++ notation for array names

Tags: c++, class, syntax

I have two classes, an appointment class and a calendar class. The calendar class has an array of appointment objects. Should the appointment array name be plural or not? I.e.:

```
appointment[] appointment;
```

or

```
appointment[] appointments;
```

Is there an agreed syntax for this situation?

**Update:** Also, do class names start with a lowercase or uppercase letter?

Comment: I cannot remember having ever seen the singular form in such a situation. So: `appointments`

Answer (score 2):

There is no convention, but you'll need to use distinct names for the type identifier and variable identifier.  I tend to capitalise type but not variable identifiers, but it's a matter of personal taste.  In this specific case of member data, a prefix or suffix also serves.

Also personal taste, I do tend to use the plural for a container, and have a suspicion it's more common.  But, countering that, I've often thought it makes sense when talking about the entire container, while from an English reading perspective "appointment[3]" as "appointment three" reads better than "appointments three".

Answer (score 1):

There is no agreed naming convention, but I would make two suggestions:

1. Use an `std::vector<appointment>`
2. Give data members some special pre-fix or suffix, for example `appointments_` or `m_appointments`

Personally, I find the plural form more intuitive when referring to a collection.

Comment: Would call the conventions using suffixes and/or prefixes archaic ones.

Answer (score 1):

> Should the appointment array name be plural or not?

Yes, off course. Because it contains multiple appointments.

> Is there an agreed syntax for this situation?

That depends on the [coding conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coding_conventions) within your organization, team or department. How you are going to name variables, classes, etc depends on this.

Answer (score 1):

There are no real universal conventions.  If you're working in a team,
the team should establish conventions, and everyone should adhere to
them.  With regards to the conventions:  it's important to be able to
recognize type names, since you cannot parse C++ without knowing whether
a symbol is a type name or not.  One frequent convention *is* to have
type names start with an upper case character, and other names
(functions, variables, etc.) to start with lower case.  It's not
universal, however.  In theory, at least, it should be clear from the
name itself: the usual "rule" is that type names are unqualified nouns,
variable names qualified nouns, and functions verbs.  In practice, the
distinction between qualified and unqualified nouns isn't always that
clear, and (in English, at least), it's not always certain whether a
word is a verb or a noun.  I find it useful to distinguish 1) types from
other symbols, and 2) members from non members.

With regards to plurals, it depends.  I find that the distinction
between e.g. `appointment` and `appointments` isn't very visible.
Depending on context, I may feels it's sufficient, and use
`appointments` anyway, but in many cases, I'll go a step further, and
call it `setOfAppointments` or `listOfAppointments`, or something else
which clearly indicates a container.  This is, probably, just laziness
on my part; I should really find a better name (a qualified noun,
indicating what kind of appointments: `allAppointments`, if nothing
else).

Answer (score 0):

There is no particular convention.

I will suggest HUNGARIAN notation.

please read following article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260976%28v=vs.60%29.aspx

This will give you good idea what to do.

Comment: The general consensus seems to be the Hungarian, at least as used by Microsoft, is a bad idea.  You don't want to go through and rename all of your variables just because you've changed an `int` to a `long`.